# TypeScript braces with 2 variables on function header?

Tags: typescript

```
function myFunc({one,two}:myType): returnType {
//}
```

Specifically what does `{one,two}:myType)` mean, assuming myType is a custom defined type previously.

Comment: This is the typescript naming convention, Typed function parameters using destructuring and in TypeScript

Comment: So it expects an object of `MyType`, and that object itself is destructed into `one` and `two` ?

Comment: yes thats  right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just parses incoming object with known keys
if you call `myFunc(param)`

`param` - it is the object with two keys

```
params = {
one: 'ValueOne',
two: 'ValueTwo'
}
```

And it is simplier to use already defined variable in your method then dot notation or Bracket Notation like:

```
myFunc(param) {
const one = param.one || params['one']
const two = params.two || params['two'] 
}
```

HERE you can find for details - look for Destructuring heading
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/07/how-to-use-arguments-and-parameters-in-ecmascript-6/

Comment: So in my example, MyType should contain exactly 2 keys, which will get unpacked into one, and two ?

Comment: No. `One` and `two` are required  - position in the object of these keys does not matter, and there can be any keys as you want

Comment: so MyType can have more keys, but it only will read the values for One and Two ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a code snippet from typescript

You would write these curly braces when you are declaring the argument types of a function

For example

```
addProduct({productId, productName}: { productId: number, productName: string }): boolean {
 ... function body
 return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically here you are typecasting your object with  `myType` interface. Let me demonstrate to you.

```
export interface myType {
  one: string,
  two: integer
}

sampleFunction ({one,two}: myType) {

}

// you can call the function like this.
callingFunction () {
   const obj = {one: 1, two: 2};
   this.hello(obj);
}
```

Here you are typecasting the parameter with myType Interface which has two properties. Those are `one` and `two`. And the property `one` will only take accept a string and `two` will accept an integer.